# I want connect my mobile via wifi

Tags: windows-7

I have HCL Laptop and connected internet (ACT broadband with LAN port) and I want to use internet with my mobile phone via WiFi from that laptop. How would I do this?

Comment: What have you researched/tried so far. I know this question has been asked before on here, so you can find an answer here if you have a look around.

Comment: It depends on you mobile phone being able to make a Personal Hotspot (WiFi or Tethering). What kind of mobile phone do you have? (i.e. on iPhone go to Settings and enable the `Personal Hotspot`)

Answer (score 1):

Install Virtual WiFi Router in your Laptop and follow the instruction from below link.

http://www.techyleakz.com/share-pc-or-laptop-internet-connection-to-android-mobile-via-wifi/

Comment: Ideally answers should be independent from external links, as they can be unavailable in the future...

Answer (score 0):

There's free software called [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) that can turn your Windows laptop into a wi-fi hotspot or wi-fi access point of sorts, sharing its Internet connection over Wi-Fi with any other nearby wireless devices (any wireless-capable device, running Windows 7 or not).